# How to know what silentArg to use when creating Chocolatey packages?

Tags: powershell, cmd, command-prompt, chocolatey

How do I find out what `silentArg` I need to use for creating a Chocolatey package?

I know that each installer will have different `silentArgs` but I just don't know where I can find which one has which. Also, I am using strictly `.exe` files (embedded too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to work with the documentation/support provided by the software maintainer, but I'll provide some suggestions here.

Typically, `MSI` installers support the same silent installation parameters (many will simply work with `/qn`), but sometimes an installer might support additional variables or an input file you must provide.

`EXE` installers are a free-for-all, unfortunately. It depends on what parameters are coded into the setup program to support, even for the `setup.exe` installers that call another MSI. Depending on what built the `EXE` installer, you might be able to try some common options. The following techniques are suggestions to get you started on de-mystifying different common EXE installers:

- A `setup.exe` that extracts and runs `MSIs` might be able to have the MSIs extracted and run on their own, but this is likely unsupported by the software maintainer. You will need to test this on your own per package to know if this approach will work.
- [Nullsoft Installers](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Main_Page) typically support a [common array of options](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/Chapter3.html#installerusageexamples) that can be used to deploy your application.
- [InstallShield Installers](https://www.flexerasoftware.com/install/products/installshield.html) typically support the [`/S` parameter along with an answer file](http://www.silentinstall.org/InstallShield#:~:text=), but you would still need to work with the software maintainer or read the software documentation to know what to put in the answer file.

---

As I've mentioned in other answers, the best thing you can do here is reach out to the vendor or software maintainer and ask for a deployment guide for that software, or at least documentation on how to silently install.